# Do opportunities "come up" or "come along"?

Tags: grammar

When you describe an opportunity, which one is correct?

"When the right opportunity comes up, I shall take it."

or

"When the right opportunity comes along, I shall take it."

I wrote the first sentence in an English Language exam, but my teacher told me the second one was the correct answer. I still don't understand why, but I don't want to make silly mistakes in future. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. Please be aware that this is a website for questions about methods for learning or teaching languages. Questions about how a specific language works are off topic here. The question will be migrated to English Language Learners Stack Exchange.

Comment: There's some small nuance difference between the two, but both sound natural to me. In the exam, was there a context that might make "come up" incorrect? Did your English teacher explain why the first sentence is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's a formal grammatical difference that would grant saying "that's definitely wrong".

In context, I would use "opportunities that come up" if you're sitting around waiting for opportunities and one unexpectedly present itself; I would say "any opportunity that comes along" if you're actively searching for them, and find one.

Again, this might be grammatically irrelevant, but I suspect your teacher told you that the correct answer is "comes along" simply because it sounds better and it's more commonly used in conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, a problem or an issue **comes up** , and an opportunity **comes along**.  At least that's the case in American English.

> Sorry, I can't talk now. Something's come up.